# send_keys result in "element not interactable" error on CoinGecho when attempt to enter a keyword using Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, cryptocurrency

I am trying to create a bot to get data from CoinGecho. It will enter my keywords and do the other stuff.

However, it respond with the "element not interactable" everytime I attempt to send the keys.
Here is my code snippet:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.coingecko.com/')
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
# locate text input field
p = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="search-input-field"]')
# click text input field. **Button.click will result in "elment not interactable" error, so I have used js method.**
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click", p)
# send key words
p.send_keys('usdt')
```

Result: selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable

I also tried to click the "search bar" before clicking the text input field, but still have the same error:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.coingecko.com/')
driver.implicitly_wait(5)

# locate "search bar"
p1 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="search-bar"]')
# click search bar
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click", p1)

#locate text input field
p2 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="search-input-field"]')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click", p2)
# send key words
p2.send_keys('usdt')
```

Result: same error

I had a feeling that I am not locating the correct elements. Anyone has some ideas?
Thanks in advance.

I expect that the bot will be able to send the keys succesfully.

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: there is [CoinGecko API](https://www.coingecko.com/api/documentation) - so maybe you could get data without scraping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That xpath match 2 elements, you want second one, first is hidden.

Change your XPATH to this one:

```
'//div[not(.//div[@class="tw-hidden"])]//div[@id="search-bar"]'
```

Your Code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.coingecko.com/')
driver.implicitly_wait(5)

#locate text input field
p2 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//div[not(.//div[@class="tw-hidden"])]//div[@id="search-bar"]')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click", p2)
#or just -> p2.click()

# send key words
p2.send_keys('usdt')
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I just did not know that relative path can be the problem.

I checked again to find that there are two "search bar" and two "search-input-field". 

ps: I also need to send keys to the according "search-input-field". It worked!

Comment: use this on dev tools console to "debug" xpaths: $x(your_xpath) this return matches > ex: $x("//div")

Comment: copy that, thanks!